# GlobalWorkerOptions of undefined for a React-Typescipt-Electron app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to use pdfjs-dist's [example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/webpack/main.js) for a Typescript-React-Electron app.

```
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'src/node_modules/pdfjs-
dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

I get `GlobalWorkerOptions of undefined`.

Based on what I found [here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/blob/master/src/entry.js)
in `package.json` I've put:

```
"source": "src/app/components/pdfHandling/entry/entry.js",
```

where `src/app/components/pdfHandling/entry/entry.js`:

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';

export {
 pdfjs,
};
```

I posted the same problem in Mozilla's GitHub. And this is the answer I received:

> The standalone examples in our repository work, so this must be some
> integration issue with React/Electron, for which we cannot provide
> assistance since we're not familiar with them. I would suggest to ask
> on StackOverflow or other React/Electron-specific forums instead.

Any ideas about how to make `pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions` working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was silly and subtle....

It is enough to substitute

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

with

var pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist");

to make the problem disappearing....